# No graphical interface on power off/on

Tags: shutdown, gui

I am using ubuntu trusty on both my laptop and my desktop. Unlike my laptop, my desktop has no GUI during power on/off. While this is no pressing matter, I would like to know if there is a way to change this (both ways) and why it occurs.

(The desktop has a GTX770, and the laptop is running on intel graphics.)

Image comparison of my laptop & desktop on unencrypt screen:

http://i61.tinypic.com/11sh5k7.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Nvidia for you: instead of being compatible with VESA modes, they're only VGA (and maybe SVGA) compatible, which gives you ugly boot and shut-down screens.

See also: [Linus Torvalds on Nvidia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVpOyKCNZYw)

Press <kbd>c</kbd> on grub to get in the console and then enter `videoinfo`.

Note down the highest resolution and color depth available. E.g `1920x1080x32`.
Load ubuntu and enter in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` and add the following:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32    
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

(Add your own resolution and color depth). Save it, exit and enter in the terminal:

```
echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub2
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Hey, your answer helped me find the following solution:
http://www.binarytides.com/ubuntu-fix-nvidia-graphics/
I edited it into your answer.

Comment: Fantastic!  :-)  Give someone a fish and he will not be hungry for a day; teach him how to fish and he will not be hungry for his entire life! ;-)